# Twitter:send direct message using scribe

Tags: android, twitter

Here is my code to send send direct message using scribe. But it gives me null response. What am I doing wrong?

```
 OAuthRequest req;
 OAuthService s;
 s = new ServiceBuilder()
        .provider(TwitterApi.class)
        .apiKey(APIKEY)
        .apiSecret(APISECRET)
        .callback(CALLBACK)
        .build();
 req = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages/new.format?user_id="+user_id+"&text=my app test");

s.signRequest(MyTwitteraccesToken, req);
Response response = req.send();

   if (response.getBody() != null) {
    String t=response.getBody();
    Log.w("twittersent","twittersent"+t);
 }
```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: you should replace the "format" to "xml" or "json" in your request url

Comment: @Cauliturtle i tried..but same result.

Comment: so then try to encode the text?

Comment: @Cauliturtle i'm getting response now..But results in "Couldn't authenticate you" errr..

Comment: Can you share what's the problem finally?

Comment: @Cauliturtle the text file is changed as url encoded ...And i just tried with a new API key and APi secret..that worked..thanx for ur help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the format as XML or JSON in your request URL. Also, make sure your entire text file is URL encoded.